# Is it possible to test Android app using ordinary JRE Junit test?

Tags: android, junit

Is it possible test Android app using ordinary JRE Junit test? I mean by not extending AndroidTestCase and running the tests on a phone or emulator?

I have design my app using MVP as far at is goes with Android and have a Presenter that basically knows nothing about the specific View, in this case the specific Activity. So I was hoping to run regular JUnit tests on my Presenter.

Is that possible or must I use AndroidTestCase and run the test on a phone or emulator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out it is possible, I used this guide to get it working: https://sites.google.com/site/androiddevtesting/notepadsample